# nginx and php-fpm - php requests return 404

Tags: php, nginx

When requesting `http://server-ip` the default "Welcome to nginx" page is returned.

When requesting `http://server-ip/phpinfo.php` 404 is returned. No errors in the error log, but `GET 404` in access log

If `location ~ \.php$` is removed from the conf then `phpinfo.php` is downloaded as a file when requested

## setup

```
apt-get install nginx
apt-get install php5-fpm php5-mysqlnd
```

## conf

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root        /var/www;
        index       index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files       $uri =404;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

## php cli

This works as expected

```
php -f /var/www/phpinfo.php
```

## php-fpm

```
# ps aux | grep php-fpm
root      1555  0.0  0.1 183508 20976 ?        Ss   16:20   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  1557  0.0  0.0 183508  7152 ?        S    16:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool www           
www-data  1558  0.0  0.0 183508  7152 ?        S    16:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool www           
root      1932  0.0  0.0  12720  2080 pts/0    S+   16:23   0:00 grep php-fpm
```

## nginx version

```
# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't integrate with nginx the same way it does with Apache. You'll need to launch the PHP daemon separately.

sudo service php5-fpm restart

[See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134666/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-enable-php-on-nginx) for more details.

Comment: after `service php5-fpm restart` 404 is still returned.. If `location ~ \.php$` is removed from the conf `info.php` is downloaded as file when requested..

Comment: `ps aux | grep php-fpm` == the service is running

Answer (score 0):

After using the conf files from nginx 1.6.3 it works :)